# If the polynomial $f_1(x^3)+xf_2(x^3)$ is divisible by $x^2+x+1$ then $f_1$ and $f_2$ are divisible by $x-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, divisibility

I've tried doing some kind of brute force here, but I'm pretty sure that there has to be a trick which solves this in a couple of lines. I wrote

$$
f_1(x^3)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^{3i}, \ f_2(x^3)=\sum_{j=0}^m b_j x^{3j},
$$

and then used the fact that the sum of the two is divisible by $x^2+x+1$ to obtain

$$
f_1(x^3)+xf_2(x^3)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^{3i} + \sum_{j=0}^m b_j x^{3j+1} = (x^2+x+1)q(x),
$$

where $q(x)$ is the quotient. However, I have no idea where to go from here. How do I incorporate the $x-1$ part? And how do I switch to the fact that $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are divisible by $x-1$?

I thought of maybe using the fact that $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$, but again I'm stuck on where to use it.

EDIT: Sorry, there was one $x$ missing in my formulation. The place where I found it also had the $x$ missing, but the original exercise says $f_1(x^3)+xf_2(x^3)$.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Say $f_1(x)=x$ and $f_2(x)=-1$.  Then don't I have $f_1(x^3)+f_2(x^3)=x^3-1$?  That's divisible by $x^2+x+1$ but neither $f_i$ is divisible by $x-1$.

Comment: @lulu You're right :)

Comment: @lulu Made an edit to the post, I was missing an $x$.

Answer (score 4):

$\!\bmod\, x^2\!+x+1\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{x^3\equiv 1}\ $ so $\ 0 \equiv f_1(\color{#c00}{x^3})+x\,f_2(\color{#c00}{x^3})\equiv f_1(\color{#c00}1)+x\,f_2(\color{#c00}1)$

Thus $\ x^2\!+x+1\mid \underbrace{f_1(1) + x\, f_2(1)}_{\large \rm smaller\ deg \ so\,\  0}\,\Rightarrow\,f_1(1) = 0 = f_2(1)\,\Rightarrow\, x\!-\!1\mid f_1,f_2$

Comment: **Remark** $\ $ If you don't know modular arithmetic then we can replace it as follows

$$ f_1(x^3)+xf_2(x^3)\, =\, f_1(1)+xf_2(1) + (\color{#0a0}{f_1(x^3)-f_1(1)}) + x(\color{#0a0}{f_2(x^3)-f_2(1)})$$

$x^2+x+1\,$ divides LHS so also RHS, so it divides $\,f_1(1)+xf_2(1),$ since it divides $\,x^3-1\,$ which divides both $\rm\color{#0a0}{braced\ terms}$ on RHS by the Factor Theorem: $ $ put $\,y = x^3\,$ in $\,y\!-\!1\mid \color{#0a0}{f(y)\!-\!f(1)}\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

Let $a$ be one solution to equation $x^2+x+1=0$. Then $\overline{a}$ is also a solution of this equation. Then $a,\overline{a}$ are also solution to equation $f_1(x^3)+xf_2(x^3)=0$. Since $a^3=1$ we have $f_1(1)+af_2(1)=0$ and  $f_1(1)+\overline{a}f_2(1)=0$. Thus $f_2(1)(a-\overline{a})=0$ and thus $f_2(1)=0$ and now $f_1(1)=0$ which means that $x-1$ divides $f_1$ and $f_2$.

Comment: Readers may find it instructive to introspect on how working mod both roots of $\,x^2 + x + 1\,$ (as above) is equivalent to working mod $\,x^2+x+1\,$ as in my answer (hint: CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem or equivalent)